# How to ignore duplicate key errors when inserting an updatable record with JOOQ

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I'm currently using JOOQ with updatable records following this pattern for inserts:

```java
MyRecord myRecord = new MyRecord();
try (var txn = tm.beginWriteTransaction()) {
  myRecord.setA("value");
  myRecord.insert();
  txn.commit();
}
```

After `txn.commit()`, I expect `myRecord` to be updated with values from the database, e.g. if the table has an auto-incremented column `id`, `myRecord.getId()` will return its value.

If the column `a` has a unique constraint, `txn.commit()` will throw a `DataAccessException` when it is violated.
My question is it possible to tell JOOQ to not throw an exception but still update the record with the existing values?

Answer (score 0):

There's a pending feature request to add `UPSERT` capabilities to `UpdatableRecord`: [#1234](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/2961).

In the meantime, you can embed your record in an ordinary SQL query:

```java
MyRecord myRecord = new MyRecord();
try (var txn = tm.beginWriteTransaction()) {
  myRecord.setA("value");
  myRecord = dsl
     .insertInto(MY_TABLE)
     .set(myRecord)
     .onDuplicateKeyUpdate()
     .set(myRecord)
     .returning()
     .fetch();
  txn.commit();
}
```

Comment: Does your first suggestion update `myRecord` in-place with the values from the database?

Comment: None of the solutions seem to do what I need. I need: 1- to ignore exceptions thrown when a constraint is violated 2- update the record with the value of fields with a default value or were auto-generated (when the insert is successful).

Comment: @Seed: try the updated answer. This may or may not work, depending on the SQL dialect you're using.